# Tooltip "You have new reputation changes" is not cleared

Tags: feature-request, bug, top-bar, tooltips, achievements-dialog

When getting reputation changes the icon lights up with a number, and its tooltip changes to:

> You have new reputation changes

That is fine, however when clicking the icon then closing it, the tooltip is not changing back to default. The number does go away:

> [image]

Can the tooltip also be cleared? Refresh of the page works and bring back the default tooltip.

Comment: By any chance, do you use IE ? :p (without joke maybe adding the browser version can help in case it's a bug)

Comment: @yagmoth555 that's not related to browser, tooltip is just not being changed. They don't try to change it. (Chrome for me, but sure it "happens" on all browsers.)